# Overriding scroll function within only one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-scrollable

I'm using jquery to provide clickable overlays, I'd like to replace the default Scroll up/down methods with left/right (So when you scroll the **page** it moves horizontally not vertically. I'm worried about the scroll function still working as intended within the **overlays**.

**Update:** If it's not possible to scroll the browser what about a div that has a horizontal scroll bar that on scroll up/down moves left to right (as well as anchors)

My JavaScript experience is somewhat limited, any guidance with this matter would be greatly appreciated
Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe you can override the scroll behavior, only the scroll visibility; that's up to the browser.

Comment: I've seen in done, for example this site: http://www.vanityclaire.com/ also has up/down scrolling overwritten with left/right

Comment: That site isnt using 'scrolling' in the same sense that a browser does. That site is manipulating the margin of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an appropriate solution with:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo
my code:

```
function shiftScroll(offset) {
    console.log('current:' + window.pageXOffset);
    console.log('currentY:' + window.pageYOffset);
    $(window).scrollTo(window.pageXOffset + offset, window.pageYOffset, {axis:'x'});
}
```

I still need to disable the vertical scroll bars in the body, while not disabling the vertical scroll bars in elements within the page.